# Verify if snippet is installed

Tags: javascript, ruby, code-snippets

In order to use some products like Google Analytics or Kissmetrics you have to install a snippet of Javascript. These sites let you enter a URL in order to check if the snippet has been correctly install.

What is they best way to do this check? (the only way I can see is to parse the page source but doesn't seems super efficient, specially if the snippet is behind an authenticated page)

Thanks,

Comment: Making a request to the page and using regex to match the pattern would be the obvious way to go. However it would depend on what the snippet does, does it report back to the server the snippet is being consumed from? if so, you could build something in to the host to report/set a value etc that the snippet is being consumed.

Comment: It does send data to the server but then this report would be send everytime the page is loaded (e.g.: adding loads of extra queries to the API). This check should be more a one-off thing.